# How to Draw Right Angled Triangle progress I can Fill It percentage wise

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

I need to draw something like this in the UI , And Unable to draw it in image View, Can anyone help me achieve this kind of design?[image]

Comment: Please do not ask [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706778/triangleimageview-to-draw-right-angle-triangle-in-android-kotlin?noredirect=1) twice . Add your code with question add the language Tag . I am sure you can find lots of example of drawing a triangle with Canvas online . For percentage you can use base size of triangle . `width == 100` and later you can calculate to actual progress

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late but i have to create a similar thing recently . Sharing it here, i think it can help.

```
class TriangleProgressView : View {
private var progress = 0
private var paint: Paint? = null

constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
    init()
}
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
    init()
}
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
) {
    init()
}

private fun init() {
    paint = Paint()
    paint!!.style = Paint.Style.FILL
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    drawShadow(canvas)
    if (progress == 0) return
    drawProgress(canvas)
}

private fun drawShadow(canvas: Canvas) {
    paint!!.color = Color.GRAY
    val path = Path()
    path.moveTo(0f, measuredHeight.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(measuredWidth.toFloat(), measuredHeight.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(measuredWidth.toFloat(), 0f)
    path.close()
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint!!)
}

private fun drawProgress(canvas: Canvas) {
    paint!!.color = Color.BLUE
    val height = measuredHeight
    val width = measuredWidth
    val progressX = width / 100 * progress
    val progressY = height - height * progressX / width
    val path = Path()
    path.moveTo(0f, height.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(progressX.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(progressX.toFloat(), progressY.toFloat())
    path.close()
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint!!)
}

fun setProgress(progress: Int) {
    this.progress = progress
    invalidate()
}
}
```

Now all you gotta do is call `setProgress` from the `Seekbar` listener . It should work . All the main Logic is inside `drawProgress` method . progress calculated with the help of `tan` of angle because angle stays the same .

Answer (score 0):

An example of custom view in Java. This requires a triangle image in drawable folder.

```java
public final class DrawTest extends View implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
    private final Bitmap bitmap;
    private final Paint paint;
    private final Rect src;
    private final Rect dst;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private int width, height;
    private final int imgWidth, imgHeight;
    
    public final DrawTest(final Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }
    
    public final DrawTest(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, -1);
    }

    public final DrawTest(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr)
    {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, -1);
    }

    public final DrawTest(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr, final int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        
        src = new Rect();
        dst = new Rect();
        paint = new Paint();
        
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.triangle);
        imgWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        imgHeight = bitmap.getHeight(); 
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw, final int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        
        width = w;
        height = h;
        
        src.set(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        dst.set(0, 0, w, h);
    
        seekBar = getRootView().findViewById(R.id.SeekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        seekBar.setMax(100);
        seekBar.setProgress(100);
    }
    
    public final int getWidth(final int percentage, final int width)
    {
        return (int)((width / 100F) * percentage);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int progress, boolean fromUser)
    {
        src.set(0, 0, getWidth(progress, imgWidth), height);
        dst.set(0, 0, getWidth(progress, width), height);
        invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    public final void onStartTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar)
    {}
    @Override
    public final void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar)
    {}
    
    @Override
    protected final void onDraw(final Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint);
    }
}
```